# Redondear precio entero por aproximación

Tags: php, matemáticas

He estado buscando la manera de redondear los precios de mis envíos. En la moneda chilena hay muchos ceros, asi que decidí aproximar los valores cada $500 pesos a partir de $1000 pesos. Por ejemplo:

```
1001 => 1500
1501 => 2000
2345 => 2500
2678 => 3000
```

Entendiendo esta logica pude escribir el siguiente código PHP. El problema es que quisiera optimizarlo ya que tendría que repetir la ejecución varias veces hasta llegar a $999.999 pesos. **¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?**

```
$price = 2100;

if($price >=1001 && $price <=1499 ) {
    $price = 1500;
}

if($price >=1501 && $price <=1999 ) {
    $price = 2000;
}

if($price >=2001 && $price <=2499 ) {
    $price = 2500;
}

if($price >=2501 && $price <=2999 ) {
    $price = 3000;
}
```

EDIT: Con la función ceil me deja hacer algo muy similar pero cada $100 pesos. No es cada $500 pesos pero por el momento fue una buena opción:

```
$price = ceil($price / 100) * 100;
```

Comment: `$price = ceil($price/500)*500;` si lo quieres en una sola línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo mismo, pero con un bucle, para evitar escribir tanto código:

```
if ($price % 500 > 0) {
    for ($c = 1000; $c < 1000000; $c += 1000) {
        if ($price > $c && $price < $c + 500) {
            $price = $c + 500;
            break;
        }
    
        if ($price > $c + 500 && $price < $c + 1000) {
            $price = $c + 1000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Seguramente hay una forma más elegante de hacerlo, pero esa ya te servirá.

*Actualización:*

Bueno, ésta es **una solución más elegante**:

```
$resto = $price % 500;
if ($resto > 0) {
    $price += (500 - $resto);
}
```

Comment: Carlos PHP Me sirvio de mucha ayuda! Te agradezco tu respuesta!

Comment: Gracias, le he añadido hacer el bucle sólo si `$price` no es divisible entre 500, y eso me ha dado la idea para una solución más elegante, que he añadido a la respuesta ;)